# Jquery cookie plugin not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm new to jquery cookie plugin.
i'm write code to set cookie on the one page server side and read it on another page from jquery.
it work locally on all browser.
but on the server it work Properly on ie and not working Properly on chrome and firefox.
it's my code to set cookie on the server side:

```
context.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", _token));
```

and to read and remove cookie after file download on another page with jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var fileDownloadCheckTimer;
    function blockUIForDownload() {
        var token = '1357.11.22'; 
        $('#download_token_value').val(token);
       $.blockUI({
            message:$('#domMessage'),
            css: {
                padding: 10,
                margin: 0,
                width: '30%',
                top: '50%',
                left: '35%',

                textAlign: 'center',
                color: '#000',
                border: '3px solid #aaa',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                cursor: 'wait',
            }});
            fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
                //alert(cookieValue);
                if (cookieValue == token)
                    finishDownload();
            }, 1000);
    }

    function finishDownload() {
        window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
        $.unblockUI();
        $.cookie('fileDownloadToken', null, { path: '/' });

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please set the cookie expiration date time, as server could be in another timezone which is behind browser system time.

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", _token);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10); //change this to appropriate value
cookie.Path = "/"; //Also set path
context.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```